# SQL Server Case Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question and I cant figure it out, it should be pretty quick but I haven't seen anything like it yet. So here's my main problem, I have a case statement which defines a team based on a manager so it looks like:

```
"team" = case
    when manager = 'manager1' then 'team1'
    ...
    when manager = 'managerN' then 'teamN'
    else 'Other'
end
```

Then I want to find a way to make a new column "proj" so that it is project unless team is 'Other' so I would like it to look like:

```
"proj" = case
    when team = 'Other' then 'Other'
    else project
end
```

but I keep getting error where the syntax is incorrect or it says team is not a valid column. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the exact Error ?

Comment: You can't reuse aliases in a select clause. Only after.

Comment: Invalid column name 'team'.

Comment: what do you mean re-use aliases?

Comment: select proj = case ... end, * from ( select ... team ...  ) t

Comment: so I need to do two selects?

Comment: either that or duplicate your first case statement

Comment: `"team"` needs to be replaced by the column name that you want to put these values into.

Comment: post ALL of your code, otherwise use select  case
    when team = 'Other' then 'Other'
    else project END AS 'Project'
end

Comment: For clarity, `CASE` is an *expression*, not a *statement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use Northwind
GO



select 

[Hemisphere] = case
    when derived1.Continent = 'Europe' then 'Eastern'
    when derived1.Continent = 'North America' then 'Western'
    when derived1.Continent = 'South America' then 'Western'
    else 'Other Hemisphere'
end 
, derived1.Continent
, derived1.Country
from (

select c.Country , 
[Continent] = case
    when c.Country = 'Germany' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'France' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Sweden' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Denmark' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Finland' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Switzerland' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Poland' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Norway' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Ireland' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Austria' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Italy' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Portugal' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Belgium' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Spain' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'UK' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Spain' then 'Europe'
    when c.Country = 'Mexico' then 'North America'
    when c.Country = 'USA' then 'North America'
    when c.Country = 'Canada' then 'North America'
    when c.Country = 'Brazil' then 'South America'
    when c.Country = 'Argentina' then 'South America'
    when c.Country = 'Venezuela' then 'South America'
    else 'Other Continent'
end

from [dbo].[Customers] c
) as derived1
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.  You also have the power to "Mark as Answer".  :O

Comment: haha I know, I was waiting for the time limit to run out. It told me I had to wait 3 minutes.

Comment: Why use a case statement instead of joining to a UNION or a VALUES derived table?