# SQL CASE Product Price

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query Which works great, but I also want to determine the revenue for each product (Name) which has a different price based on the distribution centre:

```
SELECT NAME, 
       ISNULL([UK - BOLTON], 0)   [UK Website], 
       ISNULL([USA - FLORIDA], 0) [USA Website], 
       ISNULL([CANADA], 0)        [Canada Website], 
       ISNULL([AUSTRALIA], 0)     [Australia Website], 
       ISNULL([AMAZON (USA)], 0)  [Amazon (USA)], 
       ISNULL([AMAZON (UK)], 0)   [Amazon (UK)], 
       ISNULL([AMAZON (FR)], 0)   [Amazon (FR)], 
       ISNULL([AMAZON (CA)], 0)   [Amazon (CA)], 
       ISNULL([AMAZON (JP)], 0)   [Amazon (JP)] 
FROM   (SELECT p.NAME, 
               ps.UNITSSOLD, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN dc.[DESCRIPTION] = 'UK Website' THEN p.UKWEBPRICE 
               END Revenue, 
               dc.[DESCRIPTION] 
        FROM   DBO.PRODUCTSALES ps 
               INNER JOIN DBO.PRODUCT p 
                       ON ps.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID 
               INNER JOIN DBO.DISTRIBUTIONCENTRE dc 
                       ON ps.DISTRIBUTIONCENTREID = dc.DISTRIBUTIONCENTREID 
        WHERE  ps.ORDERDATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-08-01 00:00:00', 102) 
               AND ps.ORDERDATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-08-20 00:00:00', 102) 
               AND p.PRODUCTCLASSIFICATIONID = 2) [SourceTable] 
       PIVOT ( SUM(UNITSSOLD) 
             FOR [DESCRIPTION] IN ([UK - Bolton], 
                                   [USA - Florida], 
                                   [Canada], 
                                   [Australia], 
                                   [Amazon     (USA)], 
                                   [Amazon (UK)], 
                                   [Amazon (FR)], 
                                   [Amazon (CA)], 
                                   [Amazon (JP)]) ) AS PIVOTTABLE
```

As you can see I have tried using a CASE/WHEN but I think I'm getting confused on how to do it. Basically UK - Bolton should pick up the UKWebPRice from the Product table (p) etc for each distribution centre, and It's revenue, so it'd be UnitsSold * UKWebPrice etc for each center.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Can you add some sample data and some more explanations so we can try to help you ;-) or even better, set up an example on SQL fiddle so we can understand whats going on

Comment: You can check this example.........  But it's hard to know what you're after.  Post some DDL and sample data please.       Butt guess suggestion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235320/sql-server-case-statements/15235415#15235415

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to add a couple of columns representing revenue for each distribution centre - same as it was done with amount of products sold. 
If it's so, you need to change your Revenue definition and supply additional description column for one more pivot.

```
 ps.UnitSold * CASE WHEN dc.[DESCRIPTION] = 'UK Website' THEN p.UKWEBPRICE 
                 -- WHEN dc.[DESCRIPTION] = 'USA Website' then p.USAWEBPRICE
                 -- ...
 END Revenue, 
 'S'+dc.[DESCRIPTION]  as [RevenueDescription]
```

All that's left is to add pivot: `sum(Revenue) for <values in [RevenueDescription]>`
and columns in top query just as with sales amount.

Hope it helps - I don't have access to Management Studio so can't check if query is 100% correct.

PS. You might consider changing the data model. Separate columns for product price in each distribution centre looks like a bad idea to me - why not move it to separate table (product, distr_centre, price)?